# balances brackets problem(always the output is good)

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I have to write a program which balances a string with brackets.I wrote the program but it doesn't matter which string I enter because the program always says that the string is good.
Here's the code:

header file

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_
#include <string>

struct Element {
    char data;
    Element* link;
};

typedef Element* Stack;

void initStack(Stack& S);
void push(Stack& S, int a);
void pop(Stack &S);
int top(Stack& S);
bool isEmpty(Stack &S);
bool goodPair(char deschis, char inchis);
bool check(std::string s);

#endif
```

functions file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "header.h"
using namespace std;

void initStack(Stack& S)
{
    S = nullptr;
}

void push(Stack& S, int a)
{
    Element*nou = new Element;
    nou->data = a;
    nou->link = S;
    S = nou;
}

void pop(Stack& S)
{
    Stack aux = S;
    S = S->link;
    delete(aux);
}

int top(Stack& S)
{
    if (isEmpty(S))
        return int();
    return S->data;
}

bool isEmpty(Stack &S)
{
    if (S == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool goodPair(char deschis, char inchis)
{
    if (deschis == '(' && inchis == ')')
        return true;
    else if (deschis == '[' && inchis == ']')
        return true;
    else if (deschis == '{' && inchis == '}')
        return true;
    else if (deschis == '<' && inchis == '>')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool check(std::string s)
{
    Element* S;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == '(' || s[i] == '[' || s[i] == '{' || s[i] == '<')
            push(S, s[i]);
        else
        {
            if (s[i] == ')' || s[i] == ']' || s[i] == '}' || s[i] == '>')
                if (isEmpty(S) || !goodPair(top(S), s[i]))
                    return false;
                else
                    pop(S);
        }
    }
    if (isEmpty(S))
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}
```

main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "header.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Stack S;
    initStack(S);
    string s;
    cout << "Write the string:";
    cin >> s;
    if (check(s))
        cout << "Good";
    else
        cout << "Bad";
    return 0;

}
```

I used a stack and I traversed each character.If the character is an opening bracket I put it in the stack.When the character is a closing bracket, I compare it with the top of the stack.If it's good I pop the top of the stack.

Comment: not the problem, but this is nasty: `typedef Element* Stack;`, because it hides the `*` from declarations and causes several surprises in your code, eg `Stack aux ... delete aux;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a pointer to `Element` (aliased as `Stack`) `S` in `main()` and initialize it with `nullptr` using `initStack()` and then you do not use this variable anymore. Instead you create a local `S` in function `check()` and use it uninialized, which leads to UB.

Looks like you get confused by naming as you call of them `S` (variable in `main()`, variable in `check()`, all reference parameters all called `S`). It is not illegal to do so, but looks like you confused yourself. (you even called `std::string` lowercase `s` to increase confusion)

Also you have logical error in your function:

```
if (isEmpty(S))
    return false;
else
    return true;
```

should be opposite, if stack is empty then string is balanced, not vice versa. So replace it with:

```
return isEmpty( S );
```